# Timepass or Passtime - I'm confused between InE and IntE

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, indian-english, word-usage

Two definitions straight from the Oxfordcitionaries

> [pastime *(n)*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pastime?q=pastime) - *An activity that someone does **regularly for enjoyment** rather than work; a hobby.*
>
> [timepass *(n)*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/timepass) - *The action or fact of passing the time, typically in **an aimless or unproductive way.***

The latter word is Indian English. Though the dictionary has not mentioned this word as a *verb*, here, it's common to say (though in an informal way) *"Don't timepass, the work has to be finished in an hour."*

What if I want to refer pastime as timepass and timepass as pastime. In other words, what if I want to ask a native speaker that how does s/he passes her time (timepass) and an Indian about how does s/he does pastime?

An example for the native speakers on timepass:

> *"Narendra, why are you throwing stones in the river?"* ~ *"Ah, I'm waiting for my friend. She hasn't come yet."*
>
> *"And throwing stones?"* ~ *"Just simply... timepass."*

Here, **by no means** timepass is done for enjoyment. Nor is it a hobby.

**Note:** To most of Indians, pastime is actually timepass. Because if you ask about pastime, you are *very likely* to get an answer about *timepass.*

Comment: The expression [pass the time](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/pass-the-time?q=pass+time) comes to mind for referring to timepass. I should note that it would also be much more common to say "What pastimes do you enjoy?" then "how does one do pastime?"

Comment: What @Samuel said. Although [**kick one's heels**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kick+one's+heels) is often used in contexts where it means *be forced to wait*, it does also get used in completely "voluntary" contexts to mean ***pass [the] time [of day] aimlessly***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only users of Indian English can tell you how to express the 'Standard English' sense of *pastime* in Indian English; and to all appearances **you** are our authority on Indian English dialects.

I might remark, however, that *pastime* is literary or academic and is not often encountered in colloquial registers. "What do you do as a pastime?* is far more likely to be

> What do you do for fun? *or*
> What do you do for amusement? *or*
> What do you do for a hobby?  *or*
> Do you have any hobbies?

For a Standard English equivalent of InE *timepass* in the contexts you present, I suggest *waste time* for the first and *kill time* or *pass the time* for the second.

> "Don't waste time, the work has to be finished in an hour."
>
> "And throwing stones?" ~ "Just killing time."  *or*
> "And throwing stones?" ~ "Just passing the time"

Comment: Thanks for having faith on me. :) I never use timepass but always prefer 'killing time' instead. But timepass is too common so I simply wanted to confirm. I'm not sure how many Indians are here on this board, I sought their inputs as well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason timepass exists in Indian English is not because Indians do not know the phrases "kill time" and "pass the time", but because it carries a meaning that is subtly different from other similar/equivalent expressions. For example,

"How did you like the movie?" "I will say it is a timepass movie."

Now, how else would you express the same meaning, and, I might add, so succinctly? You might say you could say "a time-waste movie" but that would mean you didn't enjoy at all whereas you do enjoy "a timepass movie". On the other hand, a pass-time movie or a kill-time movie sound just ludicrous, aren't they?